# Using wget over ssh with a terminated session

Tags: ssh, wget

I have a RaspberryPi. I want to download a big file with `wget` but the problem is that once I log into the Pi and use `wget` to download the file, it will abort the download when I close the session.

How can I force wget to continue the download after the session is terminated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at `screen`

1. Connect to the RaspberryPi via ssh
2. Create new screen session `screen -S mySession`
3. Start wget `wget http://example.org/file.big`
4. Detach Screen Session `strg+a strg+d`

Now you can exit from the ssh-session. After some time you want to check if the download has finished. On the RaspberryPi simply do `screen -r` to re-attach the screen session

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNU_Screen

Comment: `screen` is an awfully heavy handed solution when `nohup` exists.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to continue to download with the flag `--http-keep-alive`.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `wget` in the background like so:

```
wget link & disown
```

The `wget` process will continue to run in the background, even if you close the terminal or log out of the remote machine.

Another way would be to use `byobu`. This is very similar to the method [xx4h](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136537/28893) proposed (byobu even uses screen sometimes), but I consider it easier.

Install byobu. This will depend on what Linux distribution you are running on your Pi. If it's Raspbian you should be able to use:

```
sudo apt-get install byobu
```

I'm not familiar with Arch, but if you are running Arch I'm guessing you should know how to install it.

Then run:

```
byobu
```

Start your `wget` process and press <kbd>F6</kbd>. You can now log out of the remote machine. When you come back, running `byobu` again will connect to the session you started earlier with your `wget` process.